# How to Print T-1 Date Value to Excel Sheet

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I would like to print a T-1 date value to excel, however, I am not getting the desired result.

This is my code below:

```
import os
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


report_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

Workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("C:\\Users\\SChogle\\Documents\\Projects\\Python Projects\\Web Scraping\\Date.xlsx")

Worksheet1 = Workbook.add_worksheet("Imp Pen")

formatdict = {'num_format': 'yyyy/mm/dd'}
fmt = Workbook.add_format(formatdict)
Worksheet1.set_column('A:A', 30, fmt)

Worksheet1.write('A2', report_date)

Workbook.close()

file = "C:\\Users\\SChogle\\Documents\\Projects\\Python Projects\\Web Scraping\\Date.xlsx"
os.startfile(file)
```

I expect to see, for example if running the code today, "2019-04-09" in excel. Instead I am seeing "2019-04-09  12:51:03 PM" I do not want the timestamp, only the date.

Comment: It may be some OS configurations on your end, if I run your code i get a correctly formated `date` only column, showing `2019-04-10`...

Comment: hey, do you have any idea how I could change it? Would I just go to date and time settings? Also - does it show "2019-04-09" in the formula bar as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it seems to produce the expected result:
[image]

Update: If you don't want the time part then use `date` instead of `datetime`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

report_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: hey yes I get the same value, however, it shows the timestamp in the formula bar. However when I simply type "2019-04-09" into an excel cell it does not show a timestamp in the formula bar. I am writing this information into a system and the timestamp seems to be causing an issue